# Is it possible to change the value of a prop in a vue component from methods

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component called `book`

my layout page

```
<book :item="{{ $item }}" :next="{{ $anotherBook }}" inline-template>
     <span>@{{ bookDetail.name }}</span>
     <div v-for="(book,index) in sameauthorbooks">
         <a href="#" @click.prevent="changeBook(book)">@{{ book.name }}</a>
     </div>
</book>
```

And in my .vue file

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
         props:['item','next'],
         data: function() {
             bookDetail:this.item,
             sameauthorbooks: this.next,
         },
         methods: {
             changeBook(item) {
                   this.bookDetail = item;
             }  
         }
    }
<script>
```

I have tried doing this but this is not changing the name of the book in `<span>@{{ bookDetail.name }}</span>`

Is there anything missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
export default {
    props:['item','next'],
    data: function() {
        bookDetail:'',
        sameauthorbooks: this.next,
    },
    methods: {
        changeBook(item) {
            this.bookDetail = item;
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.bookDetail = this.item;
    }
}
```